# CloudPage redirect to landing page not working - Error 500

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, journeybuilder, cloudpage

I need some help with creating a Cloud Page that need to redirect customers to a landing page. When the customer land on the page this should be counted as action and trigger a 'Wait Until API Event' in a journey.

The scenario is that the client want to have an email send then a waiting time of 5 days but during this 5 days if the customer click on any of the email links they want a follow up email to be send within 1 day.

I have little to no experience with CloudPages and coding so I used an example from this article: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/04/29/using-the-wait-until-api-event-activity/

Here are the steps:

1. I've set up the API Integration in MC as ‘Server-to-server’
2. I create a CloudPage using the code below.
3. I've updated the following parameters in the code using the 'endpoint'; 'client Id; 'client Secret'; 'EventDefinitionKey' (generated from the Wait Until API Event which I created); and the Redirect link.

   //authenticate to get access token
   var authEndpoint = 'https://{{your endpoint}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'  //add your tenant specific endpoint
   var payload = {
   client_id: {{client Id}},            //add your client id
   client_secret:{{client Secret}},     //add your client secret
   grant_type: "client_credentials"

and

"EventDefinitionKey": {{Wait Until Activity API Key}},

and

Redirect('Landing page link here',false);

4. When I was trying to publish the page I'm getting '500 - Internal server error.'

**Here is the whole code I used:**

```
%%[
SET @emailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

/* if needed, fetch other parameters passed from the CloudPagesURL function*/

IF NOT EMPTY(@emailAddress) THEN
]%%
   
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
 
   var email = Variable.GetValue("@emailAddress")
   
   //authenticate to get access token
   var authEndpoint = 'https://{{your endpoint}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'  //add your tenant specific endpoint
   var payload = {
       client_id: {{client Id}},            //add your client id
       client_secret:{{client Secret}},     //add your client secret
       grant_type: "client_credentials"
   };
   var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
   var contentType = 'application/json'

   var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
   if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
       var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
       var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
       var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url
   };

   //make api call to release subscriber from the Wait Until Activity
   if (email != null && accessToken != null) {
       var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
       var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
       var jsonBody = {
           "ContactKey": {{ContactKey}},                      //pass the Contact Key
           "EventDefinitionKey": {{Wait Until Activity API Key}},   //add the Wait Until Activity API Key
           "Data": {
               //in the payload pass any data required in your data extension and 
              //include the data as defined in the filter criteria in Wait Until Activity definition
           }
       };

       var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "/interaction/v1/events";

       var fireEntryEvent = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
       var respo = fireEntryEvent.Response.toString();
  
     if (fireEntryEvent.StatusCode == 201) {
       Redirect('https://www.salesforce.com',false);  //define the link where subscriber should be redirected
     }
   };

} catch (error) {
   Write("<br><h2>Sorry, something went wrong.</h2><br>" + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
%%[ELSE]%%
Sorry, something went wrong.
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested it from an actual email? It needs an email address to work

Comment: I have the CloudPage added to an email address yes. Is this what you mean @zuzannamj ? The issue is that when the page is published I'm getting error 500 even if I click the link from the email. There is something within the code which causing the issue but I can figure out what.